# Magento product overview and detail separated view

Tags: magento, view

I want to handle the product overivew separataly to the product detail view. I want to add additional text right behind the price in the product deatil view.

I tried to edit the view.phtml in path app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml, refreshed caches and so on, but nothing changed.

In catalog.xml view.phtml will be load. So its seems correct.

But even when I try to echo "test" it doesnt show anything.

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
 <div class="short-description">
   <div class="std"><h2><?php echo $this->__('Details:') ?></h2>
   </div>
 </div>

 <?php  echo "test";

endif;?>
```

Do you have any hint?

Regards
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable **template path hints** in the backend to check which template file is used to render product page. Make sure that the cache is also disabled.

Comment: in category product overview and product detail view both use the price.phtml. But I only want to add some information to the price on detail view. Is there a variable or anythings else what I can use for a ifelse function? if(productdetailview) echo "additional text benieth price" else "regular expression".